# Webview can't type in, is that because of missing setting?

Tags: java, android, facebook, webview

I have an Android application that connects to Facebook to request authorization of an Application.

I use the following setting in the WebView, but once the view is loaded, I can't type in login details. What I am missing?

```
WebView webview;
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.facebookview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new FacebookWebViewClient());

webview
    .loadUrl("http://www.connect.facebook.com/login.php?return_session=1&nochrome=1&fbconnect=1&extern=2&connect_display=popup&api_key="
            + FConnect.API_KEY
            + "&v=1.0&next="
            + FConnect.SUCCESS_URL
            + "%3Ffb_login%26fname%3D_opener&cancel_url="
            + FConnect.CANCEL_URL
            + "%23fname%3D_opener%26%257B%2522t%2522%253A3%252C%2522h%2522%253A%2522fbCancelLogin%2522%252C%2522sid%2522%253A%25220.741%2522%257D&channel_url="
            + FConnect.XD_RECEIVER);
```

[alt text http://img100.imageshack.us/img100/2100/facebookconnect.png](http://img100.imageshack.us/img100/2100/facebookconnect.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue.  It ended up being because the webview did not have initial focus. I was originally opening a dialog on the webview.  When the dialog closed, I saw what you are describing. When I removed the dialog it worked.

Look closely at the Facebook login page as well.  Before the input fields, there are links to Facebook policies, etc.  In some cases, it seemed like those links had focus and not the input fields.

Check BFFPhoto on the market.

Carmen

Comment: But actually I can't get focus even if I click or tap on the editfields. How do you put that focus there?

Comment: webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);